# insert data in correct sequence, though not all values currently exist

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I have a text file and I want to update (only "insert") via a ksh script.
I would like to insert the text in the correct order; however all values do not currently exist.

My text file would have data like:

```
## This file is used for ...
## 

## The user below belongs to Training 13:
99 TNG13

## The user below belongs to Training 21:
14 TNG21
```

My plan is to have the ksh script create the text I want to insert into a tmp file:

```
## This user below belongs to Training 17:
12 TNG17
```

I'm guessing that I would then use sed or awk to find the spot and use

My problem is, I need to find the section that contains the TNG entries, find where my new entry belongs, then insert the new data.  I can't sort the entire data, as I need the comments above the actual data to stay with the data!  In this case, I would like to insert my data after the TNG13 entry...since I'm adding a TNG17.  (the numbers in front of TNGXX is random is no real use for identifying the row needed)

Appreciate any assistance you might be able to provide!

KSL.

UPDATE:

I've come up with a solution, perhaps not the cleanest!.  I can see two scenarios where this solution would have problems:
1.  If the entry I'm trying to update is "TNG1" as it will have no reference!
2.  If the entry I'm trying to update has the TNGxx in a commented line.

My ksh solution (so far):

```
myid = `echo $USERNAME|cut -c4-6`
tng_id = $myid

while [[ $tng_id > 0 ]]
  do
    grep tng$tng_id $file1 > /dev/null
      if [ #? = '0' ]; then   
        PATTERN = "tng$tng_id"
        echo "Creating entry after $PATTERN"
        sed -I "/$PATTERN/a \\ \n# Creating entry for tng$myid" $file1"\n
        break
      fi
  (( $tng_id-- ))
done
```

Comment: if you expect that there will be multiple members of (for example) `Training 17`, best to include that in your sample data, as it would affect possible recommendations. You might also indicate the driving need for this project: is this something you want for yourself to learn with, or something you will use yourself, or at the other end, is the a solution for a corporate training dept with 100K+ employees? In any non-learning case, why wouldn't you do this in a database, or at least make the data layout easier to allow the updates that you need? Good luck.

Comment: All good questions.  First, the numbers are assigned, per user, outside of my software.  The software I run requires the entry in a flat file; if the entry exists.  Unfortunately, I can't change the software.  I have a script that looks at this file FIRST and if the entry does not exists the script currently warns and exists.  Since I can grab the information during the running of the script I was hoping to offer to populate the flatfile while running the script.

Comment: sorry, but still hard to understand your intent. You say "I need to find the section that contains the TNG entries". Do you mean that there are multiple sections of different kinds of data in your file? Or are the SNG entries (or similar) that you will also need to process? In you above, is TNG17 the new data, and it needs to be in between TNG13 and and TNG21? Required output from sample inputs would make this easier to assess. Signing off for a while. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;
use autodie;


$/="";open(my $fh,"<",shift);my @a=<$fh>;close($fh);
$/=undef;open($fh,"<",shift); my $temp=<$fh>;close($fh);
my $pat=qr/^\d+\s+TNG(\d+)/m;
my ($key)=$temp=~$pat;

my @ind=grep($a[$_]=~ $pat,0..$#a);
my $ii; my $found=0;
for (@ind) {
    my ($keyi)=$a[$_]=~$pat;
    $ii=$_;
    if ($keyi>$key) {
        $found=1; $temp.="\n";
        last;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    $ii=$ii+1; $temp="\n".$temp;
}
splice(@a,$ii,0,$temp);

print join("",@a);
```

Run it from the command line as `./p.pl file tmp.txt` where `file` is your text file and `tmp.txt` is the temporary file.

Comment: I've made some progress in ksh, but whenever I try to post my updates, the comment block closes out whenever I hit enter.  How do I enter my text in the comment block like @Håkon Hægland did above?  The help file says to put to blank spaces at the end of the line...not working for me.  FOr my solution, I've basically found a way to do this, but my sed statement is not putting a cr after the comments.  Will post what I have as soon as I can figure out how to put a line feed in my comment block!

Comment: @leonhardtk What do you mean by `the comment block closes out` ?

Comment: I've clicked on "Add Comment" to post my results, but as soon as I hit 'enter' for a new line, it submits my comment.  But I just wanted a new line to start posting my results...?  Perhaps I should do "Answer Your Question" instead of "Add Comment"?

Comment: @leonhardtk Try holding down the shift key while pressing enter.. Also note that my response above was an answer, and not a comment :) If you have solved your question in another way, you could either update your question, or post the solution using `Answer your own question`. It it usually not a good idea to post a solution as a comment below another solution or answer..

Comment: Gotcha.  
Still new at this...
Thanks, for the tip.  I've taken your advise and added my
progress to the original question...Not a perfect solution, and not necessarily a clean solution...but will get me by..unless someone comes up with a better idea?!  THanks.  KSL.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was already closed.  For my purposes, the following solution works best.

My ksh solution (so far):

```
myid = `echo $USERNAME|cut -c4-6`
tng_id = $myid
while [[ $tng_id > 0 ]]
  do
grep tng$tng_id $file1 > /dev/null
  if [ #? = '0' ]; then   
    PATTERN = "tng$tng_id"
    echo "Creating entry after $PATTERN"
    sed -I "/$PATTERN/a \\ \n# Creating entry for tng$myid" $file1"\n
    break
  fi
  (( $tng_id-- ))
done
```

Thanks.  KSL>